# How to apply the definitions of expectation and variance without knowing what elements of a range takes a discrete random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with finite expectation, and let $a,b∈R$ whit $a≠0$.

Prove that the discrete random variable $Y=aX+b$ :

- holds for expectation $\mathsf E(Y)=a⋅\mathsf E(X)+b$,
- and for variance $\mathsf {Var}(Y)=a^2⋅\mathsf {Var}(X)$.

*Suggestion: Consider the following theorem:*

> if $X$ is a discrete random variable, with $R_X$ rank and probability
>   function $f_X$, and $g:R_X→R$ is a (measurable) function, then
>   $\displaystyle \mathsf E(g(X))=\sum_{x\in R_X}~g(x)\cdot f_X(x)$.

---

The main problem is that I know what the theorem says, but I do not know how to use it. That is, I really do not know what values take $ g (x) $ nor $ f_X (x) $.

Could you explain the theorem and how would you use it for this demonstration?

Comment: To compute $E(Y)$, apply the theorem with $$g:x\mapsto ax+b$$ To compute $E(Y^2)$ (and deduce the variance of $Y$ from $E(Y^2)$ and $E(Y)$),  apply the theorem with $$g:x\mapsto (ax+b)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

In this situation $Y : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a composition $g(X)$ where $g$ is a measurable function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Plugging $Y = g(X)$ for $g(x) = ax + b$ in the definition you gave,
\begin{align*}
E(Y) &= \sum_{x\in R_X}(ax + b)f_X(x) \\
&= a \sum_{x \in R_X}  xf_X(x) + b\sum_{x \in R_X}f_X(x) \\
&= aE(X) + b
\end{align*}
For the variance, we have by definition
\begin{align*}
Var(Y) &= E[(Y-EY)^2] \\
&= E[(aX+b - aEX - b)^2] \\
&= E[(aX - aEX)^2] \\
&= a^2 E[(X - EX)^2] \\
&= a^2 Var(X).
\end{align*}

Comment: Maybe the second part is... \begin{align*}
Var(Y) &= E[(Y-E(Y))^2] \\
&= E[(aX+b - aE(X) - b)^2] \\
&= E[(aX - aE(X))^2] \\
&= a^2 E[(X - E(X))^2] \\
&= a^2 Var(X).
\end{align*}  like this?

Comment: "In this situation $Y$ is your measurable function $g : R_{X} \to R$" Sorry but this is so wrong... No, $Y$ is not $g$, actually $Y=g(X)$ for some well chosen $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: Carlos Frostte, is your question whether or not $E(X) = EX$? Yes that is what I meant. @Did Sorry I wasn't rigorous. I was trying to give a quick (but stupid) intuitive way to view the problem.